# i am getttig error saying foregin key constrint

Tags: c#, sql, .net

here is full error

### SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Bookings_RoomTypes_RoomTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "HootelReservationDb1", table "dbo.RoomTypes", column 'RoomTypeId'. The statement has been terminated.

below is the model and post method of the controller

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HotelReservationSystem.ApplicationCore.Model
{
    public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookingId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ChecKIn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        //public string Email { get;set; }

        //[Required]
        //[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        //public string Contact { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; }

        public RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
        //public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }

     
    }
}


for controller
[HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> AddBooking(Booking booking)
        {
            
            {
                await context.Bookings.AddAsync(booking);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("AddBooking");
            }
            
        }
```

as i can see there is no any loops and dont know what is wrong and i am expecting as user book romm the room should be saved in booking table.

for further details about code below is the link for code

https://github.com/meprigesh/HotelReservationwithsec.git

Comment: Looks like you're passing in a RoomType that either doesn't exist in the RoomType table or it's null and it's required.

Comment: From your EF DbContext Snapshot it is clear that RoomType relation is marked as Required and not optional -https://github.com/meprigesh/HotelReservationwithsec/blob/76042bc4c81619fa00c5392b96f0a7cfca66e568/HotelReservationSystem.Infrastructure/Migrations/HotelReservationContextModelSnapshot.cs#L399

So it means that your booking instance should have non-null valid existing RoomType

Answer (score 0):

Booking table RoomType column is linked with RoomTypes table. Means you created foreign key "FK_Bookings_RoomTypes_RoomTypeId" for bookings table to link it with RoomTypes table. So the RoomType column value which you are passing from booking table should be present in roomTypes tabel also.

Go through this for further ref:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp